# Deploy large application to Elastic Beanstalk transfers all data every time

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are deploying an application with about 200MB of files to Elastic Beanstalk. We have everything in git and have used `eb init` (v. 3.0.9 with Python 2.7.6) and friends to set up deploys.

When we use `eb deploy` everything deploys properly but `eb` transfers all 200MB of files every time. We were assuming that since everything is set up with git, it should only transfer changes.

We have the same problem when using `aws.push` with `eb` version 2.

What is the best way to quickly deploy a large application like this? Depending on the Internet connection, the transfer takes 5-10 minutes. We'd like it to take less than one minute.

**Edit:**

We discovered that `eb` v3 transfers all files by design--see [this AWS Developer Forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=583202&#jive-message-583087). I'd be interested to know if anyone has a better way to do deploys. Maybe something that takes advantage of git changesets.

Comment: which files takes so much space in your git? why not store them in s3 instead?

Comment: @Tal 3rd party code libraries take up 95% of the space. I don't know a way to keep them elsewhere but copy them into the application folder after deploy while retaining the ability to update those libraries periodically. If you have any suggestions on that, I'm all ears.

Comment: What language are you using? Typically you can have the instances pull dependencies rather having to include them in your application bundle that you send.

Comment: The language is PHP. It is possible to put post-deploy scripts in .ebextensions/scripts/post-deploy but AFAIK that usage is not officially supported. There is no guarantee that those scripts will run at all, and if they do run that they will finish before the server is put back into the cluster. We don't want the application to break because the dependencies are not downloaded yet. We also found that pre-deploy scripts that modify the source tree don't work because the uploaded application files are copied to /var/app/current after the pre-deploy scripts run. If that is wrong, I'm all ears.

Comment: actually pulling the libraries by using a pre-deploy script is exactly the way to do it. it is also guaranteed by EB to work.

Comment: @Tal, do you know if any code examples with that approach?

Comment: kendsnyder - Any updates to your findings.  I'm looking to deploy a large application and wondering if you were able to solve the issue.

Comment: @alloyking Not much new to report. As that AWS forum thread mentions, `eb` uses `git archive`. We were able to reduce the size of the archive by creating a .gitattributes file that lists files to exclude from the archive (e.g. readme, unit tests, etc.). See here: http://alexbilbie.com/2012/11/exclude-objects-with-gitattributes/ . Ideally I'd like to see AWS better document deploy-related hooks. We've found trial and error the best way to see the order of the hooks and when files get copied over.

Comment: A very similar question has been discussed here: [Elastic Beanstalk “git aws.push” only commited difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941775/elastic-beanstalk-git-aws-push-only-commited-difference)